# How to add a new line within JS confirm message to be shown on click of a link?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, newline

I'm trying to add `\n` but this breaks the `onclick` event – no message is popped up at all.

It works OK when I remove the **\n** character.

```
<?php
echo "<a href='logs.php?clear=true' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure:\n To delete this\");'>Clear</a>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double backslashes, the first will be interpreted by PHP. Try this instead:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='logs.php?clear=true' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure:\\n To delete this\");'>Clear</a>";
```

Though you may want to use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead:

```
<?php
echo <<< HTML
<a href="logs.php?clear=true" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure:\\n To delete this');">Clear</a>
HTML;
```

Or, even better, use proper event binding like with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
<?php
echo <<< HTML
<a href="logs.php?clear=true" id="clearconfirm">Clear</a>

<script>
    $("#clearconfirm").click(function(e) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure:\\n To delete this")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>

HTML;
```